# How to test canActivate with karma + jasmine in angular 2?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, testing, karma-jasmine

Angular 2 v.2.0.0 - TS + karma + jasmine.

I would test this canActivate function:

```
    public canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.serverThisLogin.checkAuth().map((e: boolean) => {
        if (e) {
            return true;
        }
    }). catch(() => {
        this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
        return Observable.of(false);
    });
}
```

How implement this? When i add this construction

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        canAct = new CanActivate(null, null);
    });
```

i've got this error `'CanActivate' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
 import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";
 @Injectable()

    export class CanActivateInit implements CanActivate{
      constructor() {}
      canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        if (/*somthing*/){
            return true;
        } else {
          return  true;
        }
      }
    }



import {CanActivateInit} from "./canActivateInit";
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";
export function main() {
  describe('CanActivateInit canActivate', () => {
    let canActivateInit : CanActivateInit;
    let next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
    let state: RouterStateSnapshot;

    beforeEach(() => {
      canActivateInit = new CanActivateInit();
    });

    it('should activate page' , () => {
      let result = canActivateInit.canActivate(next, state);
      expect(result).toBeTruthy();
    });

  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! I paste youe code, and now i have this error in canActivateInit - `Cannot find name 'canActivateInit'`, they are not initialized

Comment: sorry relpace canActivateInit with canActivate

Comment: OK, and now error in `canActivate = new CanActivate();` - `'CanActivate' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: can you post all your activate file?

Comment: i just posted the full ts's